# Problem in result value lesser than -180° from Madgwick AHRS

Tags: matlab, orientation, sensors

I implemented code to get orientation estimation with `accelerator`, `gyroscope`, and `magnetometer` using [Madgwick AHRS algorithm](https://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/).

I guess it worked out well. However, in some range of the data, result values under -180° have a problem: values are "lifted up." I couldn't find the right words for this, so I attached the figure below. I looked into the code but did not get any clue how to fix this problem. I followed the sample code given by the repository [here(Matlab code zip file)](https://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/). I want to know how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

[image: Problem]

Comment: Simply your values below -180deg get wrapped to +180. -190deg is the same as 170deg. An if condition in the data will fix this, depends how you want to plot it

Comment: Are you looking for the `unwrap` function? Please note, it works on radian, not on degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really appreciate your help @AnderBiguri and @Daniel! Sorry for my late reply.

`unwrap` function worked beautifully. This gave me inner peace of my mind.

Before `unwrap`:

[image: Before unwrap]

After `unwrap`:

[image: After unwrap]